# Prove $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{e^{itx}\frac{1-\cos{x}}{x^2}dx}=\frac{1}{2}(|t+1|+|t-1|-2|t|)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{1-\cos{x}}{x^2}dx}$

Tags: integration, proof-explanation, improper-integrals

This is a japanese graduate school’s entrance examination problem.
Sorry, I have NO idia at all. Please teach me how to prove the equation.

$\frac{1}{2}(|t+1|+|t-1|-2|t|) = 0,(|t|>1)$

This is what I know about this question.

Comment: The question in the title and the question in the question are different.

Comment: Also, I think there may be a sign error in both questions.

Comment: If $t>1$ then $|t+1|=t+1$, $|t-1|=t-1$ and $|t|=t$ etc.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I corrected sign error.

Answer (score 1):

We use the formula
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin (tx)}{x}dx = \frac \pi 2,\quad t >0.
$$
Define
$$
g(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i tx} \frac{1 -\cos x}{x^2} dx.
$$
We have $g(t) = g(-t)$. Hence, it is enough to consider $t \geq 0$. For $t \geq 0$, we have
$$ g(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(tx) \frac{1-\cos x}{x^2} dx = 2 \int_0^\infty \cos(tx) \frac{1-\cos x}{x^2} dx.$$
By integration by parts,
$$g(t) = -2\int_0^\infty \cos(tx) (1-\cos x) \left(\frac 1x\right)'dx = -2t\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(tx) (1 -\cos x)}x dx + 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(tx) \sin x} xdx.$$
Using the formula
$$\sin(tx) \cos x = \sin((t+1)x) + \sin((t-1)x), \quad \cos(tx) \sin(x) = \sin((t+1)x) + \sin((1-t)x),$$
and the integral above, we get the result.

Comment: I am sorry, but though the general idea is good, there are different things that are either insufficient or not exact. First of all, you need to work with sign function, from the beginning : $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin (tx)}{x}dx = \frac \pi 2 sign(t)$. Besides, a factor $\tfrac12$ in front of the RHS of your 2 last formulas is missing, and these two right formulas, when plugged into the integrals, will not give you absolute values but expressions with "sign" function : $-t(sign(t+1)+sign(t+1)...$ and you have to prove, by distinction of cases, that it coincides with the expressions of the OP

Comment: Moreover, it is not because $g(t)=g(-t)$ that you are authorized to replace an integral by its real part, it is because you can split your integral into $\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{it}...+ \int_0^{\infty} e^{it}...$ and that, due to a change of variable in the first integral, you have  $\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-it}...+ \int_0^{+\infty} e^{it}...= \int_0^{+\infty} (e^{-it}+e^{it})...= \int_0^{+\infty} (2 \cos(t))...$

Comment: I don't want to insist (especially since you are a commited contributor to this site), but you should acknowledge my remarks and correct this answer accordingly (I will erase these comments afterwards).